# How to read/poll kafka messages periodically instead of continuously

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka producer and consumer. Producer is not what I can control, and here I'm trying to define the consumer's behavior.

While producer's producing more than enough data to be consumed, I would like the consumer to poll the message every second to use instead of polling it continuously like below:

```
consumer.subscribe("topic")

while True:
    message = consumer.poll(1.0) #the parameter here is timeout I believe
    if message not None:
        logger.info(message)
        #or some logic here
```

How can I make the consumer to read/poll the data every second, instead, and skip/not necessarily consume the messages in between?

e.g. messages by producer come in like at 0.1 sec, 0.5 sec, 0.9 sec, 1.3 sec, etc... and I'd like to read only 0.1 sec's and 0.9 secs, then 1.7 sec, ... etc., instead of polling every one of available messages.

Thanks!

Comment: can you explain what you mean with "skip the messages in between"?

Comment: also, you are writing about "poll the message every second". Does it mean you have exactly one message in the topic?

Comment: @mike There are countlessly many messages in the topic that consumer's polling from, and the consumer reads more than one messages in one second now. I would like the consumer to poll one message every second, though. I feel like I could do while with sleep(1sec) instead of while True to achieve this; however, I am not sure if there's a better way because this is my first time using Kafka.

Comment: Still not getting it. Which messages exactly do you want to consume: assume the producer is producing messages at time 0 sec, 0.1, 0.7, 1.2 sec. Do you want to read the messages at time 0 and 1.2 second, or do you want to read all 4 messages but only one per second?

Comment: oh I see what you're asking @mike. I meant the former, not reading all messages.

Comment: okay, I suggest that you make this more clear in your question. It usually also helps if you describe the motivation behind this use case. It is not that I have seen everything around Kafka, but I have certainly never seen a use case like this before :) Are you sure, Kafka is the right thing for this?

Comment: @mike haha the data I need to use is being produced by kafka, and I can come up with a consumer that subscribes to the topic. Not sure how else I can use the data...

Comment: What is stopping you from writing an if statement to skip messages you don't care about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> make the consumer to read/poll the data every second

Sleeping the poll loop is not possible since this will result in the consumer group rebalancing and not consuming at all. You could *stop* the consumer entirely, then sleep, then resume, but you may want to keep track of offsets manually if you do this, for consistency.

> skip/not necessarily consume the messages in between?

I don't see why this wouldn't work for you

```
message = consumer.poll(timeout)
if should_skip(message):  # TODO: define your logic
    continue
process(message)
```